# Why does JavaFX work differently outside NetBeans?

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, javafx

I made a Java application (JDK 1.7) using Netbeans 8.1 and JavaFX.

The basic idea is a grid filled with letters, the rows and columns are sequentially highlighted to allow a person to chose a letter with a single key press (spacebar). Once the number of characters is equal or greater than 3, I implemented an autocomplete feature that fetches word starting with those letters and ranks them by lexical frequency.

It works really well when I run the project from inside the IDE but when I try to run it outside the following happens:

- when I start the program, input doesn't work for a long time (10-15 seconds... although sometimes it works almost instantly and sometimes it takes even more time)... but once it starts detecting my key presses again, it works 100% of the time. It's not limited to the spacebar (also "+" and "-" used to manipulate the speed of the highlighting). Also, the program isn't frozen, I can resize stuff just fine and the row/columns are animated.
- I also put a label next to the row where I put my autocomplete suggestions. Said label is supposed to be tilted -90°. Whenever I run it from outside Netbeans, it loses its rotation. Note: I don't use a CSS file, I used .SetStyle().

How can it behave differently just because I don't run the application from Netbeans?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Have you done a clean and rebuild of the project before running externally? This should ensure the jar correctly matches the code. The point here is that netbeans uses the .class files and external run uses the .jar. If the jar i out of sync you will see this problem.

Comment: Hey. Yes I tried (and tried again after reading your answer). Sadly it doesn't change anything!

Comment: Do you use the same java runtime in and outside netbeans?

Comment: Actually no. Netbeans was calling 1.7... when I double clicked on the Jar it was calling 1.8. Thank you!

Comment: If anybody is interested in why I had those bugs on 1.8: [1] Label rotation: on 1.7 when I used label.setStyle("-fx-rotate: -90") and then modified another property (e.g., color) the rotation would stay the same. On 1.8 I have to append every style property in the same statement and always mention the -90 rotation. [2] input issue: I discovered that if I right-clicked on the TextArea my animated grid would immediately start to register key presses. Sadly I don't know what I did to fix this but it had something to do with focus (as the event listener was on the root pane). On 1.7 it was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some possible reasons:

1. The *.jar* file is not up to date.

Netbeans runs from the *.class* files while running externally uses the *.jar* file.

Do a clean and rebuild and try again.

2. Different classpath.

Netbeans specifies the classpath to all the libraries it wants the app to use on the command line. What command line are you using? Are there any differences?

You can see the command line used in the output window when Netbeans runs your app (you may need to enable a verbose form of output - with Maven you can add --debug).

3. Security problems that take some time to resolve if you have reduced privileges.

Many people give Netbeans administrator rights (allows it to create *jar* files for example). This may not be the case on the command line.

Try running the *.jar* from a command prompt with admin rights.

4. *(Inspired by the actual problem - thank you @BlackRainbow)* - The Netbeans project will be bound to a specific Java version. When run from the command line using just `Java ... -jar ...` you will get the latest Java version which may be different.

Try running it from the command line selecting a specific version of Java. Something like `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7\jre\bin\java" ...` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! the problem was that it was using Java 1.8 instead of 1.7... If I use 1.7 everything works fine. Is there a way to force 1.7 on people... and if they don't have it, stop execution?

Comment: @BlackRainbow It's recommended to package the JRE along with your application (see the javapackager tool and JavaFX Ant tasks and JavaFX Maven Plugin) or to use Java Web Start and fix the JRE version there (also see the deployJava JavaScript).

Comment: @BlackRainbow Please note that Oracle's Java SE 7 reached End of Life and it's thus highly recommended to upgrade to Java SE 8 unless you have support contracts with Oracle. But even then: for JavaFX applications Java SE 8 is recommended.